# Is there a way to assert an expected exception with Apache beam PAssert?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-beam

I am building unit tests for a class which runs in an Apache beam pipeline.
One of the methods I'm testing should throw an exception after attempting some operation on a `PCollection`. Is there a way to expect this exception with `PAssert`?

for example

```
//Expect SomeClass to throw an exception when instantiated with this argument
val invalidParDo = ParDo.of(new SomeClass("This is an invalid parameter"))

val actualOutput = inputPCollection.apply("",invalidParDo)
//Here I'd like a way to assert that I expected a particular exception
PAssert.that(someWayToExpectExceptionHere)
testPipeline.run()
```

Or any similar alternative

Answer (score 0):

Note that `PAssert` is a Beam transform that validates that a given `PCollection` is equal to one or more given values. Exceptions raised in `invalidParDo` that are not handled will result in a pipeline failure (after retries) hence it's not possible to validate such failures in a subsequent step. But if you update `invalidParDo` to generate an invalid value instead of raising an exception, you should be able to validate the generation of such invalid values using a `PAssert`.